# How to query against many tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a database application for an award.  It has a 75 year history and numerous categories that have changed over time.  Right now, the design I am thinking of has two kinds of tables:

```
entities
    people
    publishers
categories
    novel
    movie
    author
    artist
```

and such like.  Each category has data particular to that category, for example:

```
NOVEL
title       varchar(1024)
author      int      #FK into people table ID
publisher   int      #FK into publisher table ID
year        year(4)
winner      bool

or

ARTIST
name    int
year    year(4)
winner  bool
```

So far so good.  However, there are 38 (!) of these categories that have existed over time (some do not exist anymore) and I really can't imagine doing a query for say, all of the winners from 1963 by doing:

```
SELECT * from table1,table2,...,table38 WHERE year=1963 and winner=TRUE;
```

These tables will never be that large (each category usually has at most five nominees, so even after a 100 years, there would be at most 500 rows per table and at a lot less for the early ones that aren't continued). So this isn't a performance question.  It is just that that query feels very, very wrong to me, if only because every query will have to be changed every time a new category is created or an old one removed.  That happens every few years or so.

The questions then are:

- is this query evidence that I've designed this wrong?
- if not, is there a better way to do that query?
- I keep thinking there must be some way to create a lookup table which pulls from other tables, but I could be misremembering.  Is there some way of doing such a thing?

Many thanks,

Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with 3 tables.

First one is *entities*. It contains data about all publishers/artist/etc.

```
entities

    name   varchar(1024)
    publisher  bool
```

Second is *data* where all data from all categories is stored.

```
data

title       varchar(1024)
author/name      int      #FK into people table ID
publisher   int      #FK into publisher table ID
year        year(4)
winner      bool
category    int      #FK into category table ID
```

Third is *category* in which you can find all categories names with their IDs.

```
category

ID int
name varchar(1024)
```

Now you have to join only three tables.

```
select * from entities e, data d, category c where d.name=e.name and d.category=c.id and winner=bool and year=1963
```

Comment: Nimle's point about the slug is an interesting idea, but I think tilda hit the nail on the head.  The way to collapse all of the tables into one table is to have the data table contain the union of the fields from the 38 tables.  If I allow them to be NULLable, then for example, Best Novel might have the data.director field null but something for data.author and vice-versa for a movie.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would better to have a table for categories where you can save category key value, or just normal category table and you can save the row's id only in other table: 
for example,

Table: Category

columns: id, name, slug, status, active_since, inactive_since etc...

In slug, you can keep slugified form of cat to make it easy for queries and url: for example, Industry Innovations category will be saved as industry-innovations.

In status, keep 0 or 1 to show if it is active now. You can also keep dates when it was active and when became inactive in active_since and inactive_since fields.

When you search, you can search those have status 1 for example etc. I dont think your problem is complex and it is very simple for mysql to search when you join tables.

There are projects where dozens of tables are joined and it is ok.